# How to move items positioned on a draggable image when the image is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable, imagemap

I have an image (map) in a div, on which other images (markers) are placed. I made the image draggable by using JQuery:

```
jQuery("#map").draggable();
```

and that works. The problem is, that when the image is dragged, markers don't move with it, they stay still in the div.
I haven't so much experience with JS/JQuery, neither with CSS. How can I make markers move with the image?

Here is the structure of the page:

```
<div id="mapDiv">
    <img src="../data/mappa.jpg" class="map" alt="porto" usemap="#mappa" id="map" />
    <map name="mappa"></map>

    <a id="acol1201" class="point col1201">
       <div>
           <area shape="circle" coords="1663,991,5" href="#" class="mappedpoint" id="col1201">
           <img src="./res/img/icons/green_dot.png" class="marker" id="col1201">
       </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

and here the css:

```
img.marker#col1201 {
   top: 991px;
   left: 1663px;
}

#mapDiv {
   position: absolute;
   left: 19vw;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   margin: 0;
   width: 81%
   cursor: grab;
   cursor: -moz-grab;
   cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

#map {
    padding: 0;
}   

.marker {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: A quick solution would be if you "redraw" the markers once the drag event is complete.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find out how to get how many px the image moved horizontally and vertically.

I tried as follows:
function dragPointsWithMap() {
  
 `$(".marker").each(function(index) {
  $(this).css('top', (parseFloat($(this).css('top')) + $("#map").offset().top) + 'px');
  $(this).css('left', (parseFloat($(this).css('left')) + $("#map").offset().left) + 'px');
     
 });

};`

this moves the dots, but it moves them only horizontally and too much in relation to the movement of the map. Where am I wrong?

Comment: can you make https://jsfiddle.net/ with your code so that I can look at it :)?

Comment: Can you just add another div inside of `#mapDiv` but containing all related elements and make that draggable or make `#mapDiv` draggable instead of `#map`?